# Virtual table with fixed values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to have a virtual table with fixed values?

I have the next query

```
SELECT 
    d1
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(date) AS d1 
     FROM table1 
     WHERE date IN ("2018-01-01","2018-05-04")
    ) t1
    RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT "2018-01-01","2018-05-04" ) t2
ON t1.d1=t2.?;
```

dates are going to be the same.

I want to get null if there is no entries with those dates.

But I need an alias in the question mark.

Or maybe I need something else.

How could I create a virtual table like this one, just to use it in a join.

```
-- Temp table --
value
2018-01-01
2018-05-04
```

I would like to avoid any CREATE (temp table).

Because with `SELECT 1,2,3` I get horizontal values instead of vertical.

Maybe this example explain better.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49f04/4

select date, date from dates where date in ("2018-01-02","2018-01-04","2018-01-06");

```
# What I want to show is
#
# date1      date2
# 2018-01-02 null
# 2018-01-04 null
# 2018-01-06 2018-01-06
```

As there is no info for the first two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT '2018-01-01' as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT '2018-05-04' as dte
     ) d LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT date AS d1 FROM table1 WHERE date IN ("2018-01-01","2018-05-04")) t1
    ON t1.d1 = d.dte;
```

This answers your specific question.  I'm not sure what you really want to do, but this is a pretty common querying technique.

Comment: What I want to do is get the filters values if they exist in the table otherwise I would like to get null. Dates are filters I am going to set in my app. So if myfilters are "2018-01-01","2018-02-01 and I dont have data for those dates I would like to see two records with null. My dates are dynamic so they can be 1 or more.

Comment: I like your approach, just I don't know if there is a better way to set the values you set with UNIION ALL. I would like to avoid adding SELECT date as dte UNION ALL for each date added.